# uSiteBuilder 3.0 loads DocumentType fields but not the DynamicNode fields

Tags: umbraco, umbraco6

I've encountered a problem working with Umbraco 6.1.5 and uSiteBuilder 3.0.0 where when I instantiate a strongly typed DocumentType using `ContentHelper` all the fields defined in the DocumentType are loaded into the object but fields like `Name`, `Id` or `Children` aren't loaded (they're null, empty or 0).

From what I can tell it's because the `ContentHelper` method responsible for instantiation is calling the empty constructor for `DynamicNode`. Is there something I'm missing? Should I be defining constructors on my Document Types?

Here's my DocumentType:

```
namespace USiteBuilderTest.DocumentTypes
{
    [DocumentType]
    public class Home : DocumentTypeBase
    {
        [DocumentTypeProperty(Name = "Field 1")]
        public string Field1 { set; get; }

        [DocumentTypeProperty(Name = "Field 2")]
        public string Field2 { set; get; }

        [DocumentTypeProperty(Name = "Field 3")]
        public string Field3 { set; get; }
    }
}
```

In-case it's helpful, here's the part of the code that's calling the empty constructor:

```
Type typeDocType = DocumentTypeManager.GetDocumentTypeType(node.NodeTypeAlias);
    if (typeDocType != null)
    {
        ConstructorInfo constructorInfo = typeDocType.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(int) });
        if (constructorInfo == null)
        {
            retVal = (DocumentTypeBase)Activator.CreateInstance(typeDocType);
        }
        else
        {
            retVal = (DocumentTypeBase)constructorInfo.Invoke(new object[] { node.Id });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that despite the Codeplex project description clearly stating that branch "3.0.0" should be used with Umbraco v6 there's actually a specific v6 branch that should be used instead (labelled "version6API").

Credit for the answer goes to Vladan Ostojic who answered the question on the Umbraco forums:

http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/usitebuilder/usitebuilder-support/44774-uSiteBuilder-30-loads-DocumentType-fields-but-not-the-DynamicNode-fields?p=0#comment161011

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this problem. A solution could be to add an empty constructor and a constructor that has nodeid as input. Like this:

```
namespace USiteBuilderTest.DocumentTypes
{
    [DocumentType]
    public class Home : DocumentTypeBase
    {
        public Home() {}

        public Home(int nodeId) : base(nodeId) { }

        [DocumentTypeProperty(Name = "Field 1")]
        public string Field1 { set; get; }

        [DocumentTypeProperty(Name = "Field 2")]
        public string Field2 { set; get; }

        [DocumentTypeProperty(Name = "Field 3")]
        public string Field3 { set; get; }
    }
}
```

That did the trick for me.